# My approach to deal with the effects of randomness in a ML model

Tags: machine-learning, classification, randomness

I'm not a statistician, so please excuse a possibly wrong use of terminology here.

My dataset has about 400 - 800 samples and about 800 features. The samples are ordered by time, although it is not a time series. There are three class labels (exclusive), which are not highly imbalanced, but slightly imbalanced.

I have a custom metric to check how well a model performs, which is not usable for training, but can be used to evaluate it afterwards (very computationally expensive).

I'm using a training set, a validation set, and a test set. The test set is fixed (last *x* recent samples), but depending on how i choose the training and validation sets, e.g., for a MLPClassifier, the outcome on my custom metric varies greatly.

To deal with this, i build a few hundred models, each with a differently shuffled training/validation set. Then i compare them on my custom metric with the fixed test set. Among the models, i can then select the best performing one.

The disadvantage is that i have to train a few hundred models every time a new number of samples are available and then select the best one for the next prediction period.

**Is the overall approach sound? Is there a better approach?**

I read things like stochastic weight averaging might help, but as far as i understand this only helps to reduce the randomness introduced by the different starting weights of a neural network, not with variance introduced by having different training/validation sets.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building different models or are you just shuffling the train/validation sets while retaining the parameters of the model? I think [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) is what you are searching for in general if you want to build a robust model.

Comment: It's the same model, just different training / validation sets. I am using CV, but i cannot use it with my custom metric really because it takes minutes to calculate.

Comment: Can you maybe show your error metric?

Comment: not really, sorry. it's another algorithm that selects among options based on the predictions of the model. maybe i could simplify it to a degree and then use it directly as the training metric.

Comment: I think it might be helpful to use a simplified version of your error metric for cross-validation, especially if it is very different from common metrics. Otherwise your algorithm might optimize for a different target which could result in the test error discrepancies.

Comment: Thanks! Actually i could solve it by building my own scorer function and hide relevant data for evaluation in the features. it's a bit of a workaround but seems to do the job.